# Labels not show in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I try to make a highcharts app with angular and Asp.Net and i want to make the chart with data from asp.net so i made a function parseChartData  to do that but when i run the app data labels are showing "slice" instead of real names and don't show me the data values , i don't know why.

Can you please help me?

This is my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { Order } from 'src/app/shared/order';
import {Customer} from 'src/app/shared/customer';
import {SalesDataService} from '../../services/sales-data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private  _salesDataService:SalesDataService) { }
 


  @Input() inputData:any;
  @Input()  limit:number;
  
  highcharts=Highcharts;
  
  public  options: any = {
    chart: {
    type: 'pie'
     },
    title: {
    text: ''
     },
     plotOptions: {
       pie: {
       
       dataLabels: {
      enabled:true,
      
      },
      showInLegend: true
       },
    
    
    tooltip:{
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
       
       },
      
    
      series: [{
  
        name: '',
        data: []
        
      },{
        name: '',
        data: []
      },{
      name: '',
      data: [],
       }
      ]
    }

  

  ngOnInit() {
    

    this.parseChartData(this.inputData,this.limit);
    
  }


 parseChartData(res:any,limit? :number){
   console.log('response:',res);
   const allData=res.slice(0,limit);
   console.log('allData(slice):', allData);

   


 this.options.series=[{data:allData.map(x=>x['total']),
  name:allData.map(x=>x['name'])
}]


 Highcharts.chart('container2',this.options);
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot

Comment: Sure,i edit my question.

Comment: Please use the official Highcharts Angular wrapper - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular which is fully supported by Highcharts. If the issue still will occur - please reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: I have the same problem and i can't reproduce my code in online editor because i use data from Asp.net.

Comment: And i notice that when i use "name" here: name:allData.map(x=>x['name']) my labels show togheter. Ex:"ReadyCleaner,ReadyBakery   : 1743"

Comment: @It seems that the `data.name` is not defined in your data. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nvgp2hd4/

Comment: Can u post the this.options json ? After chart rendering

Comment: I solved the problem,data.name was no defined.